# mount Linux server

Tags: linux, mount, windows

I have two Linux servers, I am able to mount one of them from Windows Server 2016 but not able to mount the other one. I am getting this error

```
System error 1240 has occurred.

The account is not authorized to log in form this station
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

I am able to mount same server from Windows Server 2008.

What will be the issue?

Comment: I would do a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=samba+%22the+account+is+not+authorized%22) and find out which of the many answers matches your particular situation. There might also be some information in the Samba logs, especially after increasing the log level.

Comment: Do you mean "log into..." or "mount a network drive from..." the Windows Server? Also it is best to crop an image before uploading *and* add the error in text format, as it is not possible to search an image for text strings.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in the picture is `System error 1240 has occurred. The account is not authorized to log in from this station.`

According to [this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/521867/442837), this error message may indicate that the Windows server 2016 has the `Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)` setting applied to it, and the Linux server has not been configured to support SMB signing, i.e. the `server signing` setting in `smb.conf` is set to `disabled`.

But that means the Linux server is still using the deprecated insecure SMB version 1: in SMB2 and above, signing *cannot* be disabled, by design. The flawed SMB1 protocol was one of the main reasons the WannaCry worm and its variants managed to spread so effectively. You **really** should get the Linux system to use SMB2 or above, so that you could completely disable SMB1 support.

Another possible explanation is that the message may mean exactly what it says: the Linux server can have a list of clients it will allow for a share, and if such a list exists, then the Windows Server 2016 system apparently isn't on that list (the `hosts allow`/`allow hosts` settings in `smb.conf` file).